# What's the simplest way to make a TCP to SSL wrapper in Python?

Tags: python, node.js, multithreading, ssl, tcp

What's the simplest way to have a local TCP server that wraps connections connects to a remote server using TLS and pipes the TCP connections in TLS ? I'm trying to achieve the following in node.js:

```
var tls = require('tls');
var net = require('net');
tls.createServer(function (socket) {
    var conn = net.createConnection('remote-server.com', 28016);
    socket.pipe(conn).pipe(socket);
}).listen(28015);
```

I'm imagining I'll be needing threading.Thread right ? My main issue is that I don't see any `pipe` method in the [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html) class.

Comment: Sidenote: why does the title of the question say "in Python" and also include a tag for Python if this is a node.js question?

Comment: It's not a node.js question, I just included node.js code to explain what I would like to achieve in Python